# Using Boomi how can I create a flat file profile which has "line" data on the same physical line in the flat file as the "header" data?

Tags: integration

I've got parent & child data which I am trying to convert into a flat file using Dell Boomi. The flat file structure is column-based and needs a structure where the lines data is on the same line of the file as the header data.

For instance, a header record which has 4 line items needs to generate a file with a structure of:

> [header][line][line][line][line]

Currently what I have been able to generate is either

```
[header][line]
[header][line]
[header][line]
[header][line]
```

or

```
[header]
[line]
[line]
[line]
[line]
```

I think using the results of the second profile and then using a data processing shape to strip `[\r][\n]` might be my best option but wanted to check before implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a user define function for each field of data.  For this example, lets just speak for "FirstName."

1. I used a branch immediately-Branch 1 Split the documents, flow controlled them one at a time, and entered the map, then stopped.  Branch two contained a message where I built the new file.  I typed a static value with the header name, then used a dynamic process property as the parameter next to the header.
2. User defined function for "FirstName" accepts the first name as input, appends the dynamic process property (need to define a dynamic property for each field), prepends your delimiter of choice, then sets the same dynamic process property.

This was all done with NO scripting at all.  I hope this helps.  I can provide screenshots if you need more clarification.

Comment: Correction: For each function, prepend your delimiter first, then prepend your dynamic property, then set the property.